# How do I change the background image in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

This is my code:

```
def bathRoom():
    global drag, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j
    bg_bathroom = True
    bathroom = pygame.image.load("pou_bathroom.jpg")
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    gameDisplay.blit(bathroom,[0,0])
    gameDisplay.blit(pivi,[200,80])
    gameDisplay.blit(soap,(a, b))
    gameDisplay.blit(shower,(c,d))
    gameDisplay.blit(shop,(e,f))


    if click[0] == 1 and a + soapWidth > mouse[0] > a and b + soapHeight > mouse[1] > b:
        drag == 1      
        a = mouse[0] - (soapWidth / 2)   
        b = mouse[1] - (soapHeight / 2)


    if click[0] == 1 and c + showerWidth > mouse[0] > c and d + showerHeight > mouse[1] > d: 
        drag == 1
        c = mouse[0] - (showerWidth / 2)
        d = mouse[1] - (showerHeight / 2)


def main_loop():
    while True:        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               quit()

        mainScreen()
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if click[0] == 1 and x + bathWidth > mouse[0] > x and y + bathHeight > mouse[1] > y: 
        bathRoom()
        pygame.display.update()
```

This is the part that I try to change background.
After I click the image I need to display a new background but it just displays for 0.5 seconds. I need it to stay then I will be the one to change it again.

```
main_loop()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: Welcome to SO, a general guideline for people trying to get help with GUI code is to remove as much code as possible from the question without destroying the integrity of the code. For instance you don't really need to show us `global drag, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j` or code not related to the background image. This not only speeds up our helping process but it also helps you not scare away lazy helpers that are skilled in this area. Some might go "meh, tl;dr" when in fact they would be able to help out : ) Shorten your question, get quicker responses! Win win!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, here's the relevant code **with fixed indentation**.
Secondly, I'll assume `gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))`.

```
def bathRoom():
    bathroom = pygame.image.load("pou_bathroom.jpg")
    gameDisplay.blit(bathroom,[0,0])
    gameDisplay.blit(pivi,[200,80])
    gameDisplay.blit(soap,(a, b))
    gameDisplay.blit(shower,(c,d))
    gameDisplay.blit(shop,(e,f))

def main_loop():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if click[0] == 1 and x + bathWidth > mouse[0] > x and y + bathHeight > mouse[1] > y: 
            bathRoom()
            pygame.display.update()
```

Now since the other objects probably don't overlap the background, I'll remove those as well to make the code even easier to read.

Then I'm going to switch `pygame.display.update()` to `pygame.display.flip()` because that will actually re-render the "blitted" images entirely.

I'm also moving `bathroom = ...` outside of the function, because this will stress HW when you really don't need to.

Something alone the lines of this should work:

```
bathroom = pygame.image.load("pou_bathroom.jpg")

def bathRoom():
    global bathroom
    gameDisplay.blit(bathroom,[0,0])

def main_loop():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if click[0] == 1 and x + bathWidth > mouse[0] > x and y + bathHeight > mouse[1] > y: 
            bathRoom()
            pygame.display.flip()
```

Also please consider changing whatever `IDE` you're working in.
It leaves artifacts at the end of the lines and ruins your indentations.

Here's a citation from the manual:

> pygame.display.flip   —   Update the full display Surface to the screen
>   pygame.display.update     —   Update portions of the screen for software displays

`update` *should* work, but generally unless you want to update small areas, use `flip` because it's more reliable and honestly faster at some times (even tho they claim it shouldn't be).